# How do I delete rows greater than 6 months old , but ensure I have at least 100 rows left in a table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Consider the following table definition:

```
FooTable
   ID int,
   TimeStamp datetime,
   Data varchar(50)
```

I would like to keep only the recent 6 months of data, but also make sure that I keep a minimum of 100 rows of data in the table. How do I do this?

I know how to remove data greater than 6 months old:

```
DELETE
FROM FooTable
WHERE TimeStamp <=  DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

How do I add the condition of maintaining at least 100 rows of data in the table (regardless of how hold the data is)?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using, e.g. SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
WITH todelete AS (
      SELECT f.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) as seqnum
      FROM FooTable 
     )
DELETE FROM todelete
WHERE seqnum > 100 AND
      TimeStamp < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE());
```

This deletes the oldest timestamp but being sure that they are deleted only after the 100th record.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will use this code in **SSMS** to clean data so you will not care if it is including some variables.

So, my solution is this:

```
DECLARE @CURRENT_NO INT
SELECT @CURRENT_NO = COUNT(*) FROM xTable WHERE timstamp < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
DECLARE @DEL_NO INT
SELECT @DEL_NO = CASE WHEN @CURRENT_NO < 100 THEN 100 ELSE @CURRENT_NO END 
DECLARE @DEL_ROW_NO INT
SELECT @DEL_ROW_NO = COUNT(*) + @DEL_NO - 100 FROM xTable WHERE timstamp > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
DELETE TOP (@DEL_ROW_NO) FROM xTable WHERE timstamp < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
SELECT * FROM xTable
```

I have tested it using the script below (minimised version):

```
CREATE TABLE xTable (timstamp DATETIME, qty INT)
INSERT INTO xTable VALUES
('2020-11-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), 
('2020-11-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5), ('2020-01-01', 5)

DECLARE @CURRENT_NO INT
SELECT @CURRENT_NO = COUNT(*) FROM xTable WHERE timstamp < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
DECLARE @DEL_NO INT
SELECT @DEL_NO = CASE WHEN @CURRENT_NO < 5 THEN 5 ELSE @CURRENT_NO END 
SELECT @DEL_NO
DECLARE @DEL_ROW_NO INT
SELECT @DEL_ROW_NO = COUNT(*) + @DEL_NO - 5 FROM xTable WHERE timstamp > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
SELECT @DEL_ROW_NO
DELETE TOP (@DEL_ROW_NO) FROM xTable WHERE timstamp < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
SELECT * FROM xTable

DROP TABLE xTable
```

and the result is :

```
+-------------------------+-----+
| timstamp                | qty |
+-------------------------+-----+
| 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 5   |
| 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 5   |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 5   |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 5   |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 5   |
+-------------------------+-----+
```